# Deriving value of new column based on Group Pyspak

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a use case where I want to derive the `gender` of a `person` by doing `GroupBy`.

If the `GroupBy` contains `MALE` and `NEUTRAL` title. We can consider ther person `male`.

If the `GroupBy` contains `FEMALE` and `NEUTRAL` title. We can consider ther person `female`.

If the `GroupBy` contains only `NEUTRAL` title. We can consider ther person `neutral`.

If the `GroupBy` contains `FEMALE` and `MALE` title. We can consider ther person `unknown`.

If the `GroupBy` contains only `MALE` title. We can consider the person `male`. Similarly for `FEMALE`, it would be `female`.

MALE  = ["Mr", "Lord"]

FEMALE = ["Ms", "Mrs", "Lady"]

NEUTRAL` = ["Professor", "Prof", "Dr"]

Input:

```
+--------+--------+
|  person|   title|
+--------+--------+
|SYNTHE02|      Mr|
|SYNTHE02|      Dr|
|SYNTHE03|      Mr|
|SYNTHE03|      Mr|
|SYNTHE05|     Mrs|
|SYNTHE05|      Ms|
|SYNTHE05|      Ms|
|SYNTHE01|     Mrs|
|SYNTHE01|      Dr|
|SYNTHE01|      Ms|
|SYNTHE07|      Dr|
|SYNTHE07|    Prof|
|SYNTHE08|     Mrs|
|SYNTHE08|    Prof|
|SYNTHE08|      Mr|
+--------+--------+
```

Output:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|  person|   title|  gender|
+--------+--------+--------+
|SYNTHE02|      Mr|    Male|
|SYNTHE02|      Dr|    Male|
|SYNTHE03|      Mr|    Male|
|SYNTHE03|      Mr|    Male|
|SYNTHE05|     Mrs|  Female|
|SYNTHE05|      Ms|  Female|
|SYNTHE05|      Ms|  Female|
|SYNTHE01|     Mrs|  Female|
|SYNTHE01|      Dr|  Female|
|SYNTHE01|      Ms|  Female|
|SYNTHE07|      Dr| Neutral|
|SYNTHE07|    Prof| Neutral|
|SYNTHE08|     Mrs| Unknown|
|SYNTHE08|    Prof| Unknown|
|SYNTHE08|      Mr| Unknown|
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Any suggestion and help would be deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: SYNTHE03 has only no value which corresponds to Neutral but your output shows Male, can you clarify that? I'm done with the solution just stuck here. Same for SYNTHE05

Comment: Also for SYNTHE02 - For the first two rows its Male, and for the other two it is Neutral. Please clarify that as well.

Comment: Hi @RonakJain, thanks for enquiring. I have edited the dataframes. If it is only Male, output should be Male. Same for Female. Please take a look

Comment: Posted my answer, let me know if the requirement is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
MALE = ["Mr", "Lord"]
FEMALE = ["Ms", "Mrs", "Lady"]
NEUTRAL = ["Professor", "Prof", "Dr"]

df\
.groupBy("Person")\
.agg(F.collect_list("Title").alias("Titles"))\
.withColumn("MALE", F.array(*[F.lit(x) for x in MALE]))\
.withColumn("FEMALE", F.array(*[F.lit(x) for x in FEMALE]))\
.withColumn("NEUTRAL", F.array(*[F.lit(x) for x in NEUTRAL]))\
.withColumn("Gender", F.when((F.arrays_overlap(F.col("Titles"),F.col("FEMALE")) & F.arrays_overlap(F.col("Titles"),F.col("MALE"))), "Unknown")
             .when((F.arrays_overlap(F.col("Titles"),F.col("MALE")) & F.arrays_overlap(F.col("Titles"),F.col("NEUTRAL"))), "Male")
            .when((F.arrays_overlap(F.col("Titles"),F.col("FEMALE")) & F.arrays_overlap(F.col("Titles"),F.col("NEUTRAL"))), "Female")
            .when(F.arrays_overlap(F.col("Titles"),F.col("NEUTRAL")), "Neutral"))\
.withColumn("Gender", F.when((F.col("Gender").isNull() & F.arrays_overlap(F.col("Titles"),F.col("FEMALE"))), "Female")
             .when((F.col("Gender").isNull() & F.arrays_overlap(F.col("Titles"),F.col("MALE"))), "Male")
            .otherwise(F.col("Gender")))\
.selectExpr("Person","explode(Titles) as Title","Gender")\
.show()
```

Input:

```
+--------+-----+
|  Person|Title|
+--------+-----+
|SYNTHE02|   Mr|
|SYNTHE02|   Dr|
|SYNTHE03|   Mr|
|SYNTHE03|   Mr|
|SYNTHE05|  Mrs|
|SYNTHE05|   Ms|
|SYNTHE05|   Ms|
|SYNTHE01|  Mrs|
|SYNTHE01|   Dr|
|SYNTHE01|   Ms|
|SYNTHE07|   Dr|
|SYNTHE07| Prof|
|SYNTHE08|  Mrs|
|SYNTHE08| Prof|
|SYNTHE08|   Mr|
+--------+-----+
```

Output:

```
+--------+-----+-------+
|  Person|Title| Gender|
+--------+-----+-------+
|SYNTHE02|   Mr|   Male|
|SYNTHE02|   Dr|   Male|
|SYNTHE03|   Mr|   Male|
|SYNTHE03|   Mr|   Male|
|SYNTHE05|  Mrs| Female|
|SYNTHE05|   Ms| Female|
|SYNTHE05|   Ms| Female|
|SYNTHE01|  Mrs| Female|
|SYNTHE01|   Dr| Female|
|SYNTHE01|   Ms| Female|
|SYNTHE07|   Dr|Neutral|
|SYNTHE07| Prof|Neutral|
|SYNTHE08|  Mrs|Unknown|
|SYNTHE08| Prof|Unknown|
|SYNTHE08|   Mr|Unknown|
+--------+-----+-------+
```